# How to show JIT debugger in a handled Exception?

Tags: vb.net, jit

Suppose I catch an exception only for the purpose of knowing internally that something went wrong, is there a way of still showing the JIT debugger?

Comment: This will only work on your machine, not the user's.  So a very basic way is to simply not catch the exception in the Debug build, the debugger should now automatically break to show the mishap.  Consider using #If DEBUG / Throw / #Endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [**`Debugger.Launch()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) in your code. Doing so will cause Visual Studio to open a window where you'll be able to select which debugger to use.

```
Try
    Dim s As String = Nothing
    s = s.Substring(0, 4) 'Causes a NullReferenceException.
Catch ex As Exception
    Debugger.Launch()
End Try
```

Just remember to remove this again when releasing your application.